# ¿Por qué se necesita usar «los/las» en la frase «si los hay»?

Tags: pronombres, objetos-directos, haber

No entiendo la regla gramática que rige sobre esto. No entiendo cuándo tengo que usar un pronombre «los/las/lo/la» con «hay».

No entiendo cuándo y por qué se necesitaría usar un pronombre en estos casos por ejemplo:

1. Las preguntas, si [las] hay, podemos contestarlas después.
2. ¿Manzanas? Creo que todavía [las] hay.
3. Si [lo] hay todavía usalo (el dinero) para volver a casa.
4. ¿Hay pan? Sí, [lo] hay.
5. Podemos hacer un té de boba con la leche, si aún [la] hay.

¿En cúales casos sería necesario y por qué?

Comment: Existe en este uso también algo de topolecto, pues en España esto es común, al menos con las frases que das de ejemplo, en América latina la tendencia es sin los pronombres que has puesto entre paréntesis, se oye raro, pero se entiende.

Answer (score 1):

El verbo *haber* en este contexto es un verbo impersonal de existencia, y por ende carece de sujeto. Al carecer de sujeto, eso que *hay* se expresa mediante el complemento directo.

He aquí a continuación lo que dice el DPD al respecto:

> Esta construcción es heredera de la existente en latín tardío «habere (siempre en tercera persona del singular) + nombre singular o plural en acusativo». Así pues, etimológicamente, esta construcción carece de sujeto; es, por tanto, impersonal y, en consecuencia, el sustantivo pospuesto desempeña la función de complemento directo. Prueba de su condición de complemento directo es que puede ser sustituido por los pronombres de acusativo lo(s), la(s): Hubo un problema > Lo hubo; No habrá función > No la habrá.

En español, es necesario que un pronombre tome el lugar de un antecedente definido. El verbo *haber* es igual que cualquier verbo transitivo.

*-- ¿Has visto la película?
--Sí, LA he visto.*

*--¿Has visto muchas películas?
--Sí, he visto muchas.*

*--¿Hay las películas que viste?
--Sí, LAS hay.*

*--¿Hay muchas películas allí?
--Sí, hay muchas.*